# unable to get the difference between @JoinColumn and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: hibernate

I tried the use of `@joinColumn` and `@primaryKeyJoinColumn`. both contain the two attributes `name and referenceJoinColumn`.

so what is the exact difference between these two?
when to use `@joinColumn and @primaryKeyJoinColumn`

Comment: I read the previous answers but unable to get the exact reason of using these two annotation.

Answer (score 0):

**@JoinColum** is being used to annotate a column for joining an entity association or element collection, very used with relationships.

I think this image help you understand the big difference [image: primary key joincolumn example]

Support for  joining secondary tables to the primary table is limited to primary key join columns and is specified as a **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn** annotation.
Basically **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn** is to set relationship as a FK in the space of parent-child relationship and also used with **@SecondaryTable** annotation.
The **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn** annotation is used to join the primary table of an entity subclass in the JOINED mapping strategy to the primary table of its superclass; Consider this an option if your mapping need to change the ID field name in the sub classes entities.